# Flex: Label Overflow

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface, canvas, label

If I have two sibling canvases displayed next to each other, can I have a child Label (or any child component for that matter) in the left canvas overflow outside of that canvas and on top of the next?

Something like this:

```
 ______________   ______________
| ----------------------------- |
| | Label overflow test       | |
| ----------------------------- |
|              | |              |
|              | |              |
|______________| |______________|
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Setting `clipContent` property of parent `Canvas` to `false` will get you what you want.